# Parsing CURL String using ArgumentParser

Tags: python

I am working on a project,whereby the end user inputs a CURL string,I am using ArgumentParser to parse it and convert it into the requests library format.There are some issues during the parsing for example:

```
curl_command5 = "curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' -d '{'resourceNetworkInterface':[{'ipAddress': 'ipaddress'}]}' 'https://$$opsramp_instance.com/api/v2/tenants/$$tenantId/resources/$resourceId'"
```

This is CURL string parsed. The Parser is removing the quotes around the data portion as a result it is not getting converted to JSON format. Here is a code snippet:

```
import argparse
argv = shlex.split(curl_command5.strip())

del argv[0]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('url')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--data')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--data-binary', '--data-raw', default=None)
parser.add_argument('--request', '-X', dest='method', default='GET')
parser.add_argument('--header', '-H', dest='headers', action='append')
parser.add_argument('--compressed', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-k', '--insecure', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--user', '-u', default=())
parser.add_argument('-i', '--include', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--silent', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args(argv)

print(args.data)
```

The output produced is:

```
{resourceNetworkInterface:[{ipAddress: ipaddress}]}
```

The expected output should be

```
{"resourceNetworkInterface":[{"ipAddress": "ipaddress"}]}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have some doubts if that original `curl` command would really work. That looks-like-JSON data inside is not JSON (because of the `'`s inside instead of `"`s) and those `'`s everywhere may confuse an actual shell.

Comment: The curl string works

Comment: curl parses command line arguments [using C code](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/3b52a80c054d32a641aede92e719f672e9cb847c/src/tool_getparam.c#L2423). ArgumentParser won't be able to express exactly the logic that the C code implements. There's already many projects that do exactly what it sounds like you're trying to do, with varying degrees of quality https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/blob/aa0dba4ec34c69796c5bfd12b46c3d7fe4646f28/src/util.ts

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using subprocess calls you could probably use [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/) or [pycurl](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html).

Comment: can we convert the curl string to a pycurl equivalent programmatically.

Comment: Not sure, you might need to perform the conversion yourself. [This](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-data) should get you up and running in no time though.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the main issue was with how you defined curl_command5. I updated it to use triple quotes on the outer level so that -d could use double quotes. I then used the json library to get your desired output.

```
import argparse
import json
import shlex

curl_command5 = """curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' -d "{'resourceNetworkInterface':[{'ipAddress': 'ipaddress'}]}" 'https://$$opsramp_instance.com/api/v2/tenants/$$tenantId/resources/$resourceId'"""
argv = shlex.split(curl_command5.strip())
print(argv)

del argv[0]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('url')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--data')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--data-binary', '--data-raw', default=None)
parser.add_argument('--request', '-X', dest='method', default='GET')
parser.add_argument('--header', '-H', dest='headers', action='append')
parser.add_argument('--compressed', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-k', '--insecure', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--user', '-u', default=())
parser.add_argument('-i', '--include', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--silent', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args(argv)

print(args.data)
print(json.dumps(json.loads(args.data.replace("'", '"'))))
```

Output:

```
['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-H', 'Authorization: Bearer token', '-d', "{'resourceNetworkInterface':[{'ipAddress': 'ipaddress'}]}", 'https://$$opsramp_instance.com/api/v2/tenants/$$tenantId/resources/$resourceId']
{'resourceNetworkInterface':[{'ipAddress': 'ipaddress'}]}
{"resourceNetworkInterface": [{"ipAddress": "ipaddress"}]}
```